# Php Array - String Using

Tags: php, arrays, string, using

i want to use array this string. How can i do this? i shared my results and strings

i used this code:

```
var_dump($result);
```

and the result returned this string:

```
"{
    "_": {
        "ID": "tracked"
    },
    "success": true,
    "requestTime": "2013-08-19T13:08:36-07:00",
    "test": "Sometextshere",
    "data": {
        "news": {
            "1": "Hello",
            "13": "New Text",
        },
        "date": "2013-08-19T13:08:36-07:00"
    }
}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you've posted are JSON encoded. You first need to decode it:

```
$decoded = json_decode($result);
```

You can either return the results as an object or an array. By default it will be an object and you can retrieve the results using the point-to syntax. Say you want the string in test:

```
echo $decoded->test;
```

You can also do chained point-tos to traverse the object properties:

```
echo $decoded->data->news;
```

If you prefer to work with arrays, you can add an optional argument to your decode. Here is the same things using the array argument:

```
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
echo $decoded['test'];
echo $decoded['data']['news'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but how can i use random news arrays ?
$decoded['data']['news'][13]; is random. how can i get 13?

Comment: In this instance, 13 is a string instead of an integer. You would be correct in your syntax, though. `$decoded['data']['news']['13']`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
$result = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: when i use $result["data"];
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in